# apply a Style to a Button in a UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have tried to define this style when I hover on each button in my design,like this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
<Page.Resources>
<Style  x:Key="ButtontopStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e6e6e6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" />

                            <Rectangle x:Name="Button1" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then I apply this style to every button like this:

```
<Button x:Name="res" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtontopStyle}}" PointerMoved="res_PointerMoved"/>
```

my code works well,but How can I please modify my style to be like the image above,I work on universal App
thanks for help

Update:
I have edited my code like what Sir Kory Gill said,but I get this result:
[image]

this is my code Behind with the method res_PointerMoved:

```
private void res_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            res.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 34, 13, 238));
        }
```

but the problem how can I modify the Style code to be like the First image,how can I combine two colors when hover on each Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `</<Page.Resources>` in your code is just a typo, and should be `</Page.Resources>`.  I would avoid naming your objects the same as the names of other controls like `Button` and properties like `Content`.

I *think* I understand what you are looking for, and the below is what I modified to achieve that result.  If this is not what you wanted, please describe in more detail, what you have with the code you post, and the desired result.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style  x:Key="ButtontopStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e6e6e6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Button1" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="20"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtontopStyle}}" Content="My Button"/>
</StackPanel>
```